# Location of static application settings

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm developing a Redux/ReactJS application and I have a list of application settings.

I'm trying to decide if I should have them in the store or if I should create a file which contains the settings and import it where I need it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the nature of the 'application settings'.

## For the secure things

Like API keys, etc. Use environment variables. You can use something like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to make simulating other environments easier.

## For constants

Like strings and colors and external URLs, I use a constants file with multiple exports. Then in each module I import whatever I need, like so:

```
import {
  ANIMATION_DURATION,
  COLORS,
  MODALS,
  TEXT_PADDING,
} from '../../constants.js';
```

## For environment-specific things (e.g. dev, prod ...)

For example API URLs or log levels, etc. use a set of config files. So you might have a `config-dev.js` and `config-prod.js` and then a `config.js` that returns the correct file's contents based on `process.env.NODE_ENV`

Answer (score 0):

Application settings should be just a const in some file. In this way, for different configurations, the settings can be toggled.

An example of settings file could be:

```
let apiUrl = 'http://prodUrl';

// __DEV__ defaults to true in simulator.
if (__DEV__) {
  apiUrl = 'http://devUrl';
}

export const settings = {
  apiUrl,
  registerUrl: `${apiUrl}/api/register`,
  educationUrl: `${apiUrl}/api/education`,
};
```